# how to observe a live data inside service class

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to insert some records which I get from the API to my database,
I am using a service class to do this process, I was trying to use this concept of live data inside service class, but it required my service class to be a lifecycleowner.

am stuck with how to make my service class observer to the changes in a live data

Any help will be good!!

Comment: I think you can use the liveData.observeForever(Observer) and you don't need to pass the lifecycle owner. but make sure to remove the observer using removeObserver(Observer) once you are done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your service should not be affected by activity lifecycle (`onStop()`, `onStart()` etc) then you can use [`LiveData<T>.observeForever(Observer<T>)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#observeforever) method. Like so,

```kotlin
val observer = Observer<YourDataType> { data ->
    //Live data value has changed
}

liveData.observeForever(observer)
```

To stop observing you will have to call [`LiveData.removeObserver(Observer<T>)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#removeobserver). Like so:

```kotlin
liveData.removeObserver(observer)
```

If you need to stop observing when the application is in the background, you can bind your service in the calling activity in the `onStart()` method of the activity and unbind your service in the `onStop()` method. Like so:

```kotlin
override fun onStart() {
   super.onStart()

   val serviceIntent = Intent(this, myService::class.java)
   bindService(serviceIntent, myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
}

override fun onStop() {
    unbindService(myServiceConnection)
    super.onStop()
}
```

Read on **bound services** [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)

Then, in the service

1. override `onBind(Intent)` and `onRebind(Intent)` method and start observing the `LiveData` (App is in foreground)

```kotlin
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    liveData.observeForever(observer)

    return serviceBinder
}

override fun onRebind(intent: Intent?) {
    liveData.observeForever(observer)

    super.onRebind(intent)
}
```

2. Remove `LiveData` observer in `onUnbind(Intent)` (App is in background)

```kotlin
override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    liveData.removeObserver(observer)
    return true
}
```